# C++ Display Character with Ansi Color Code

Tags: c++, linux, unix, graphics, command

I can use ANSI color codes for strings like this:

```
cout << "\033[35m" << "hello" << "\033[0m" << endl;
```

but not for individual characters that I have assigned as part of my 2D array of characters. My goal is to display:

```
myArr[6][5] = 'H'
```

in a specific color. I have tried:

```
myArr[6][5] = "\033[35mH\033[0m"
```

and also

```
myArr[6][5] = '\033[35mH\033[0m'
```

The first gives an error because my array is of character data type, so I can't assign it to a string element. The second doesn't work because the ' ' is meant for single characters, and the ANSI code has more than one character. Any suggestions? This needs to transfer onto Linux by the way (on Terminal on my mac).

Comment: What is the type of `myArr`? Can you produce a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: "neither work", What happens? A compiler error? A linker error? A runtime error? Computer catches fire?

Comment: `'\033[35mH\033[0m'` is an invalid multibyte character, not a string of any sort.

Comment: computer catches fire. just kidding, the first doesn't work because ' ' is for char and there's obviously more than just one character around ' '. The second gives error: assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'const char [11]' which is my array of char data type letters.

Comment: Well, clearly you can't store five escape codes and a letter in a `char`, so you need a different data type. Most likely, `myArr[6]` already _is_ the data type you need, so just insert the escape codes into _that_.

Answer (score 1):

why not use an object or an struct instead of a simple character

```
enum class SGRColor :int{BLACK=0,RED=1,GREEN=2,YELLOW=3,BLUE=4,PINK=5,CYAN=6,GREY=7};
class ColorChar 
{
public:
...
string getANSIColor(void)
{
...
}
private:
char _value;
SGRColor _color;
}



array<array<ColorChar ,5> , 6> myArr;
```

or overload << operator